# java: How to get my bandwidth

Tags: java, networking

Is there a library that lets me compute my bandwidth from a RIA?

Comment: What sort of "bandwidth" are you asking about?

Comment: Define bandwidth. The rate at which data will transfer is dependent mostly on *where* you're transferring data to. If it's a computer on the LAN, it'll be really fast. Same country? less fast. etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate your download speed by timing how long it takes to download a large file from somewhere. Your speed would then be given by the `size of the file downloaded / time taken`.

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth to where? From your computer to the router, Probably about 100 Mb or 1 Gb.  From your computer to the ISP, most likely anywhere from 1 Mb to 10 Mb. From your computer to some random site on the internet.  Could actually be less than what you ISP provides, depending on what type of connection the site is on, and how much traffic they have.  My point is, the "bandwidth" can only be measured by downloading some content and measuring the speed at which this occurs.  The bandwidth testing sites on the internet assume that your home connection is slower than the site they are downloading from.  Which is a good assumption, but if you tried it from another place with a faster internet connection than the speed testing site, you would see incorrect results.